# Unicode strings to byte strings without the addition of backslashes

Tags: python, string, byte, python-3.3

I'm learning python by doing the python challenge using python3.3 and I'm on [question eight](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/integrity.html). There's a comment in the markup providing you with two bz2-compressed unicode strings outputting byte strings, one for username and one for password. There's also a link where you need the decompressed credentials to enter.
One way to easily solve this is just to manually copy the strings and assign it to two variables as byte strings and then just use the bz2 library to decompress it:

```py
>>>un=b'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
>>>print(bz2.decompress(un).decode('utf-8'))
huge
```

But that's not for me since I want the answer by just running my python file.
My code like this:

```py
>>>import bz2, re, requests

>>>url = requests.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/integrity.html')
>>>un = re.findall(r'un: \'(.*)\'',url.text)[0]
>>>correct=b'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
>>>print(un,un is correct,sep='\n')
b'BZh91AY&SYA\\xaf\\x82\\r\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x80\\x02\\xc0\\x02\\x00 \\x00!\\x9ah3M\\x07<]\\xc9\\x14\\xe1BA\\x06\\xbe\\x084'
False
```

The problem is that when it converts from unicode string to byte string the escaping backslash gets added so that it cannot be read by bz2 module. I have tried everything I know and what got up when I searched.

How do I get it from unicode to byte so that it doesn't get changed?

Comment: I am still testing to see if this is your actual error, but `is` is not the correct operator to see if you have retrieved the content correctly. `is` tests for object equality, not semantic equality.

Comment: Thank you for your time, have you come up with anything? It seems that it is not possible to remove or replace one of the slashes and I don't know how to assign a unicode string as a byte string without converting it. Thank you for your comment about the `is` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslashes are present in the HTML source, so it's not surprising that the `requests` module preserves them. I don't have `requests` installed on my Python 3 environment, so I haven't been able to exactly replicate your situation, but it looks to me like if you start capturing the surrounding `'` characters, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the character sequence into a bytes array:

```
>>> test
"'BZh91AY&SYA\\xaf\\x82\\r\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x80\\x02\\xc0\\x02\\x00 \\x00!\\x9ah3M\\x07<]\\xc9\\x14\\xe1BA\\x06\\xbe\\x084'"
>>> import ast
>>> res = ast.literal_eval("b%s" % test)
>>> import bz2
>>> len(bz2.decompress(res))
4
```

There are probably other ways, but why not use Python's built in knowledge that the byte sequence `b'\\xaf'` can be parsed into a bytes array?

Comment: The use of either `requests` and the `urllib.request` libraries had the same outcome so the question was really, how do I remove the escape backslash from the string. And you answered that question as well as I could have hoped! That's a really handy tool, the `ast.literal_eval()`, which I haven't stumbled upon, until now that is. Thank you! I think I got a clue how that input works, but I'm not yet sure why I need that extra `'` around my string, would you mind enlighten me? Thanks again! (I cannot upvote because I'm new)

Comment: This is kind of complicated - I had to work through a few versions of it myself before getting it to work. Basically, the argument of `literal_eval` needs to be something that it would make sense to type into a Python prompt or put in your source code. But you still have to make it make sense in the source itself, so you need (loosely speaking) an extra layer of literal encoding. You need to give a string object to `literal_eval` that itself represents a string object. `"b%s" % test` evaluates to `"b'BZh...'"`, which is itself a literal representing the bytes array `b'BZh...'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a [solution](https://github.com/GaetanoCarlucci/Python_Challenge/blob/master/08.py):

```
import urllib
import bz2
import re

def decode(line):
   out = re.search(r"\'(.*?)\'",''.join(line)).group()
   out = eval("b%s" % out)
   return bz2.decompress(out)

#read lines that contain the encoded message
page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/integrity.html').readlines()[20:22]

print "Click on the bee and insert: "
User_Name = decode(page[0])
print "User Name is: " + User_Name
Password = decode(page[1])
print "Password is: " + Password
```